# Android Swipe Menu List view, Item not swipe before scroll list

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using Bayoz Swipe menu library for adding swipe menu in my app.
Initially after rendering list swipe menu not open after if user scroll list and then Swipe then swipe menu opens.
Below is my code -

```
<com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

below is onCreate Code -

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    initSwipeMenu();
```

and code to init swipe menu -

```
private void initSwipeMenu(){
    SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

        @Override
        public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
            //create an action that will be showed on swiping an item in the list
            SwipeMenuItem item1 = new SwipeMenuItem(
                    getApplicationContext());
            item1.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.DKGRAY));
            // set width of an option (px)
            item1.setWidth(200);
            item1.setTitle("Action 1");
            item1.setTitleSize(18);
            item1.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
            menu.addMenuItem(item1);

            SwipeMenuItem item2 = new SwipeMenuItem(
                    getApplicationContext());
            // set item background
            item2.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
            item2.setWidth(200);
            item2.setTitle("Action 2");
            item2.setTitleSize(18);
            item2.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
            menu.addMenuItem(item2);
        }
    };
    //set MenuCreator
    listView.setMenuCreator(creator);
    // set SwipeListener
    listView.setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
            // swipe start
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {
            // swipe end
        }
    });

    listView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            String value = adapter.getItem(position);
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Action 1 for "+ value , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Action 2 for "+ value , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }});
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Whats wrong in code,Please provide your feedback.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It's seems too late but I found a solution of this kind of problem. In my case SwipeMenuListView was not closing the items and I had to scroll or touch before making a swipe. So I called

> listView.smoothCloseMenu()

after making a swipe or before setting adapter in SwipeMenuListView and that solved the problem.
Hope this will help you or next viewers to solve this problem.